# Getting data from the dynamically updated fields from JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
<li>
  <div id="time"style="float: left;">
    <div id="fromtime" style="float: left;">
      <span class="fromtime">From</span><br><br>
      <input type="text" size="7" class="from_time" name='FromTime'/>
    </div>
    <div id="totime" style="float: left;">
      <span class="totime">To</span><br><br>
      <input type="text" size="7" class="to_time" name='ToTime'/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

In this portion of my form, I need to take input from the user for 'FromTime' and 'ToTime'.

On entering these values, I dynamically create another li (using jquery) just like above to have another 'FromTime' and 'ToTime' and goes on. How can I retrieve all these 'FromTime' and 'ToTime' in my servlet? When I use `request.getParameter("FromTime")` and `request.getParameter("ToTime")`, I get only the first li values.

Comment: First li values means? means when 2nd time you create li using jquery  and you enter values, then those are not received in request.getparam().. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getParameterValues() to get an array of all the values with a given name.

Answer (score 1):

Try using getParameterValues(String) instead of getParameter. If that doesn't work, just number the parameter values in your javascript.